# Add Class to span in right click and remove it when right clicked on another

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a hierarchical tree view like picture that Implemented with `ul` `li` .

[image]

I want to add Class to `span` in right click and remove it when right clicked on another node.
I have a right click function , and put this code on it :

```
        $('.SelectedNode').removeClass('SelectedNode');
        target.addClass('SelectedNode');
```

but it doesn't work.

```
<ul class="treeView">
    <li level="1" id="1">
        <i class="CollOpen"></i><span>a 0</span><i class="MobileMenu"></i><ul class="CollList">
            <li level="2" id="551">
                <i class="CollOpen"></i><span>a 1</span><i class="MobileMenu"></i>
                <ul class="CollList">
                    <li level="3" id="553">
                        <i class="CollOpen"></i><span>a 1-1</span><i class="MobileMenu"></i>
                        <ul class="CollList">
                            <li level="4" id="556" class="lastChild"><span class="SpanChart">a 1-1-1</span><i class="MobileMenu"></i></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li level="3" id="554"><span class="SpanChart">a 1-2</span><i class="MobileMenu"></i></li>
                    <li level="3" id="555" class="lastChild"><span class="SpanChart">a 1-3</span><i class="MobileMenu"></i></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li level="2" id="552" class="lastChild"><span class="SpanChart">a 2</span><i class="MobileMenu"></i></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**My right click function :**

```
$(document).bind('contextmenu', function (e) {
            var target = $(e.target);
            if (target.is(".treeView li span")) {
                RightClick(target, e);
                return false;
            }
        });

    function RightClick(target, e) { 
        menu.data('id', target.parent().attr('id'));
        menu.data('level', target.parent().attr('level'));
        $('#NodeTitle').text(target.text() + " - کد :" + target.parent().attr('id'));
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".custom-menu").finish().toggle(100).
        css({
            top: e.pageY + "px",
            left: e.pageX + "px"
        });
    }
```

Could you help me, please?

Comment: Where are you trying to add or remove Class in `function RightClick()`?

Comment: what is  `menu` here?

Comment: @Sac , yes , in function RightClick().

Comment: @Guruprasad Rao, a Variable for keep Li's id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why its not working in your case. In my case its working.. you can see the fiddle :
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tjjny2e7/)

```
function RightClick(target, e) { 
    $('.SelectedNode').removeClass('SelectedNode');
    target.addClass('SelectedNode');

    menu.data('id', target.parent().attr('id'));
    menu.data('level', target.parent().attr('level'));
    $('#NodeTitle').text(target.text() + " - کد :" + target.parent().attr('id'));

    e.preventDefault();
    $(".custom-menu").finish().toggle(100).
    css({
        top: e.pageY + "px",
        left: e.pageX + "px"
    });
}
```

Comment: I tested again. it work, when i right click on span but when i selected any thing from menu , my class was removed.